# d3 force layout: highlight nodes in a group and their neighours

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I would like to highlight the nodes and edges that are in a certain group. I have a function connectedNodes that highlights a node and its immediate neighbours.

```
          function connectedNodes() {

              if (toggle == 0) {

                  //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
                  d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
                  console.log(this)
                  console.log(d)
                  var sel_groups = new Array(d.pathway);

                  node.style("opacity", function (o) {
                      if (neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d)) {
                        sel_groups.push(o.pathway)
                      }
                      return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.05;
                  });

                  sel_groups = sel_groups.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)

                  label.style("opacity", function (o) {
                      return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.05;
                  });

                  link.style("opacity", function (o) {
                      return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.05;
                  });

                  linkText.style("opacity", function (o) {
                      return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.05;
                  });

                  group.style("opacity", 0.05);
                  groupText.style("opacity", 0.05);

                  group.filter(function(d) { if (sel_groups.indexOf(d.id) != -1) { return true } }).style("opacity", 1);
                  groupText.filter(function(d) { if (sel_groups.indexOf(d.id) != -1) { return true } }).style("opacity", 1);

                  toggle = 1;
              } else {
                  //Put them back to opacity=1
                  node.style("opacity", 1);
                  label.style("opacity", 1);
                  link.style("opacity", 1);
                  linkText.style("opacity", 1);
                  group.style("opacity", 1);
                  groupText.style("opacity", 1);
                  toggle = 0;
              }

          }
```

I like to have a function that is activated when i click on the group and the nodes (and immediate neighbours and links) in the group are highlighted. I was trying to iteratively call the connectedNode function but somehow it is not passing the node object?

```
          function highlightPathway(id) {

              if (toggle == 0) {
                  sel_nodes=graph.nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.pathway==id; })
                  sel_nodes.forEach(connectedNodes)
                  toggle = 1;
              } else {
                  //Put them back to opacity=1
                  node.style("opacity", 1);
                  label.style("opacity", 1);
                  link.style("opacity", 1);
                  linkText.style("opacity", 1);
                  group.style("opacity", 1);
                  groupText.style("opacity", 1);
                  toggle = 0;
              }

          }
```

Comment: have you done a search on SO? You are not the first to ask this.

Comment: i did, just could not find a way that could work to pass the circle object rather than the node object in the highlightPathway function.

Comment: I added a unique id to each node and tried to access the DOM but it still failed to get the node DOM: function highlightPathway(id) {

                  if (toggle == 0) {
                      sel_nodes=graph.nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.pathway==id; })

                      sel_nodes.forEach(function(node) {
                        console.log(node)
                      if (node.pathway == id) {
                          var tmp_node = d3.select("#node_"+node.id)
                          console.log("#node_"+node.name)
                          console.log(tmp_node)

Comment: adding a lot of source code to a comment does not improve reading, use the **edit** of the question. if the node has a known `id/pathway` why not just `d3.select(".node_path_"+id)` and add a custom class to the node based on `pathway`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the pathway is an attribute of the node so I realized this works:

```
              sel_circles=svg.selectAll("circle").filter(function(d){
                return d.pathway == id;
              })
```

Thanks!